# Is it possible we can automate Slack and Trello window store applications using “WinAppDriver”?

Tags: java, automation, desktop

Facing launch issue of Slack and Trello apps using ‘WinAppDriver’, we have followed below desired capability.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("app","91750D7E.Slack_3.4.0.0_x64__8she8kybcnzg4\\app!App");
trelloSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
trelloSession.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Environment and version:

- Java8
- Selenium-Webdriver 3.141.59
- WebDriver 1.1.1.3
- Appium Java client 7.0.0
- Windows10

Multiple processes get generated in task manager if I run this application manually.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Slack app is developed with cross-platform [electron.js](https://electronjs.org/apps/slack) framework, but **WinAppDriver** supports native Windows technologies like  WinForms, WPF, Win32.

It is actually possible to automate electron apps with **Webdriver**.
You need to install Spectron, Chromedriver and use one of the client libraries (WebdriverJS/WebdriverIO)

I suggest you look to the following [post](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver) to know how to setup project.

Comment: Thank you dmle for your response, but i am trying to automate desktop version of Slack and Trello using Web App driver

Comment: I'm talking about desktop versions: they are implemented with electron.js, not with WinForms. You can check it on there web site (Slack for sure). That's why WinAppDriver won't work here.